# "Error: You have already retweeted this tweet." How do I ignore tweets that I have already retweeted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter, bots

I'm make a Twitter Bot for Retweet some tweets but my bot try to Retweet the tweets that he has already retweeted...
I think i just need one command and it will work but i don't know what i can use.

Someone can help me ? :)

This is the code:

Thanks

```
var mediaArtsSearch = {q: "#lol", count: 15, result_type: "recent"}; 
function retweetLatest() {
    T.get('search/tweets', mediaArtsSearch, function (error, data) {
      console.log(error, data);
      if (!error) {
        var retweetId = data.statuses[0].id_str;
        T.post('statuses/retweet/' + retweetId, { }, function (error, response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Success! Retweet completed.')
            }
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error with Twitter:', error);
            }
        })
    }
      else {
        console.log('Error with your search:', error);
      }
    });
}
retweetLatest();
// 1000 ms = 1 second, 1 sec * 60 = 1 min --> Retweet every minutes
setInterval(retweetLatest, 1000 * 60 );
```

The code normally retweet every minutes but he gets to retweet the first time and try to retweet the tweet he had retweeted before :/

The error:

> undefined Object {statuses: Array(15), search_metadata: Object}
>   Success! Retweet completed.
>
> undefined Object {statuses: Array(15), search_metadata: Object}
>   Success! Retweet completed. Error with Twitter: Error: You have
>   already retweeted this Tweet.

etc...etc...etc...